# Java: moving ball with angle?

Tags: java

I have started to learn game physics and I am trying to move a ball with an angle. But it does not change its angle. Java coordinate system is a little different and I think my problem is there. Here is my code.

This is for calculating x and y speed:

```
 scale_X= Math.sin(angle);
 scale_Y=Math.cos(angle);
     velosity_X=(speed*scale_X);
 velosity_Y=(speed*scale_Y);
```

This is for moving ball in run() function:

```
  ball.posX =ball.posX+(int)velosity_X;
  ball.posY=ball.posY+(int)velosity_Y;
```

I used `(int)velosity_X` and `(int)velosity_Y` because in `ball` class I draw object

```
g.drawOval(posX, posX, width, height);
```

and here `g.drawOval` requires `int`. I dont know if it is a problem or not. Also if I use angle 30 it goes +X and +Y  but if I use angle 35 it goes -X and -Y. I did not figure out how to work coordinate system in Java.

Comment: change `velosity` for `velocity` It won't work anyway but it would be easier to read :P

Comment: Not to be pedantic (and, in the end, this was not related to your problem) but the 'coordinate system' is not something dictated by Java (language) but by the particular graphics library you are using. In your case, I guess, java.awt.Graphics (Java 2D API)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Math.sin() and Math.cos() expect the angle in **radians**. You should transform your angles to radians (angle*Math.PI/180).

Comment: I changed it but its not changing angle. I can see in console that Velosity_X and Y changes but ball is not changing its angle.I used class that extends JPanel and drawed my ball in here and in Main class I used JFrame  and  f.getContentPane().add(velosity);

Comment: I fixed it.Conversation worked.I  used some where wrong value .That was mistake.

Answer (score 2):

Use [Math#toRadians()](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double))

```
scale_X = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(angle));
scale_Y = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(angle));
```

Answer (score 2):

Check your types.  You probably want everything to be floats because your scale variables are going to be less than one, greater than zero.  If they are multiplied by ints, there is a good chance you will end up converting to a 1 or 0 all the time.  I'm not completely sure of this, I'd code up a few simple equations to make sure (rather than memorize all the rules) if I were you.

One way to do it is to downcast your floats (or doubles) to int at the last possible moment (when you need to pass the values to a method call).  This is a little bit of an overkill but doesn't hurt anything but CPU that you aren't using anyway--and may prevent bugs.

Comment: Am I use int or Float? If I want to get smooth movements then float is not good choice? But my ball.posX must be int and at the end I am geting INT value.